# Does "--content-base" is deprecated from webpack-dev-server while using webpack v2.2?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I started migrating webpack 2.2 here i'm facing issue while configuring webpack-dev-server,my build script is

```
  "build": "webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/"
```

Getting below error

```
ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app/index.js content-base ./src
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'content-base' in 'E:\React\react-basics'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app/index.js content-base ./src

ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app/index.js content-base ./src
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'E:\React\react-basics\src' in 'E:\React\react-basics'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app/index.js content-base ./src
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

where as if i set my script without **content-base** works properly

```
 "build": "webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server
```

Why this error occurs how to set webpack-dev-server for webpack 2.2?

Comment: I have no experience with webpack, however, you ask if  `--content-base` is deprecated? yet the "code" is using `content-base` without the `--` ... so, try using the command line flag correctly, see if that works for you

Comment: @JaromandaX No that is not that reason

Comment: so, your error message doesn't change when you use `--content-base`? Have you tried reading the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-contentbase)?

Comment: @JaromandaX --content-base is used in webpack 1 but in webpack 2.2 how to use content-base that is my query

Comment: yes, I know that

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to configure the devServer settings in the webpack config file:

[Example](https://github.com/jquintozamora/react-typescript-webpack2-cssModules-postCSS/blob/master/webpack/webpack.config.dev.js):

```
  devServer: {
        // All options here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/

        // enable HMR on the server
        hot: true,
        // match the output path
        contentBase: resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        // match the output `publicPath`
        publicPath: '/',

        // Enable to integrate with Docker
        //host:"0.0.0.0",

        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        // All the stats options here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/
        stats: {
            colors: true, // color is life
            chunks: false, // this reduces the amount of stuff I see in my terminal; configure to your needs
            'errors-only': true
        }
    },
```

And you could invode webpack-dev-server from package.json like [here](https://github.com/jquintozamora/react-typescript-webpack2-cssModules-postCSS/blob/master/package.json):

```
"start": "set NODE_ENV=development && webpack-dev-server --open --config ./webpack/webpack.config.dev.js",
```